# C# work with functions

Tags: c#

I'am new with C#. How works in C# functions?

My try:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(number_p(5)));            
    }

    public void number_p(int number)
    {
        int one = 1;
        number = number + one;
        return number;
    }
```

Error: return, why?
Thanks

Comment: Could you put what the error is in the question please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like the problem may be that your function is declared to return void (i.e. nothing).  Try changing it to return int.

```
public int number_p(int number)
{
    int one = 1;
    number = number + one;
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You Method is of type "void" so there is no return value

If you want to return a number of type int you have to declare your method to be of type int instead of void

Maybe you should grab a book and read the very raw principles of c# first before posting here

Comment: Not only C#, but the basic principles of imperative programming.

Answer (score 1):

Your function (typically referred to as a 'method' in C#) is defined as returning void. Change it to:

```
public int number_p(int number)
```